# Wrapper for pandas function of a dataframe, which reads a csv from file as the dataframe - df not defined error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, wrapper, python-decorators

I often code functions that work on a dataframe, with additional arguments. **I'd like to write a general function that I can wrap around this sort of function, which will load a .csv file as a dataframe, then use that dataframe in the function.** I'd like to have the option to also save the output as another .csv file in some cases, giving the function a file location at which to save the .csv.

The issue I am having is that this is not quite a decorator function, as it includes additional arugment(s), namely file locations (for loading a .csv, and sometimes for saving one). But **I also don't want to have to write this function uniquely for every function I want to do this with** (in which case I just pass all arguments of the contained function to the wrapping function).

My current attempt is below. I am running this in jupyter notebook, so it just saves the .csv in the home directory and loads it from there.

```
import pandas as pd

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[5,3,7,2]
testdf=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)),columns=['A','B'])

file_in_location='test.csv'
testdf.to_csv(file_in_location)

def open_file_and_run_wrapper(func,file_in_location,file_out_location='',save_output=False,delimiter=','):
    '''
    Function that opens a file as a dataframe and runs it through the given function
    '''
    if save_output==True:
        if file_out_location=='':
            # raise exception
            print('error: must have file output location')

    df=pd.read_csv(file_in_location,delimiter=delimiter)

    if save_output==True:
        df.to_csv(file_out_location,delimiter=delimiter)

    return func(df=df,*args,**kwargs)

def df_function(df,add_colname,value):
    df[add_colname]=value
    return df

open_file_and_run_wrapper(
    df_function(df,'C',4),
    file_in_location,
)
```

**This returns the following error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-d174cd4d8bbc> in <module>
     29 
     30 open_file_and_run_wrapper(
---> 31     df_function(df,'C',4),
     32     file_in_location,
     33 )

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

This is not surprising, as the dataframe is not defined when I begin running this function. However, it will be defined by the wrapper function. **How do I create a general wrapper/decorator function that allows an additional argument?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach it like this, where you pass the function as an object, then pass positional arguments and keyword arguments as a list-like and dictionary-like. It would look something like so:

```
def open_file_and_run_wrapper(
    func,
    file_in_location,
    func_args=[],
    func_kwargs={},
    file_out_location=None,
    delimiter=",",
):
    """
    Function that opens a file as a dataframe and runs it through the given function
    """

    df = pd.read_csv(file_in_location, delimiter=delimiter)
    processed_df = func(df, *func_args, **func_kwargs)

    if file_out_location is not None:
        processed_df.to_csv(file_out_location, delimiter=delimiter)

    return processed_df


def df_function(df, add_colname, value):
    df[add_colname] = value
    return df


open_file_and_run_wrapper(
    df_function, file_in_location, func_args=["C"], func_kwargs={"value": 5}
)
```

I've made some changes to your code so hopefully I haven't changed what you were expecting.

- `func_args` accepts a list or tuple (any sequence really) and are then passed to the function as positional arguments
- `func_kwargs` accepts a dictionary-like argument and pass as keyword arguments to the function
- deleted `save_output` in favor of checking whether `file_out_location` exists to save the output of the function (if no `file_out_location` is provided, then no output is saved as a file).
- moved the call to `to_csv` to save the newly created dataframe instead of saving the same dataframe that was read from the file

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can write (and call) the wrapper:

```
# notice the additional *args and **kwargs
def open_file_and_run_wrapper(func, file_in_location,
                              *args,                 
                              file_out_location='',
                              save_output=False, 
                              delimiter=',', **kwargs):
    '''
    Function that opens a file as a dataframe and runs it through the given function
    '''
    if save_output==True:
        if file_out_location=='':
            # raise exception
            print('error: must have file output location')

    df=pd.read_csv(file_in_location,delimiter=delimiter)

    if save_output==True:
        df.to_csv(file_out_location,delimiter=delimiter)

    # note how we pass the additional parameters
    # in `df_function` `df` is not a keyword argument
    # we call it as such
    return func(df,*args,**kwargs)

def df_function(df,add_colname,value):
    df[add_colname]=value
    return df
```

Now , we can call the wrapper with the additional parameters as keyword arguments

```
open_file_and_run_wrapper(
    df_function, 
    file_in_location,
    add_colname='C', value=4
)
```

Or we can also call with positional arguments but that would be less readable

```
open_file_and_run_wrapper(
    df_function, 
    file_in_location,
    'C', 4       # positional arguments here
)
```

Output:

```
   Unnamed: 0  A  B  C
0           0  1  5  4
1           1  2  3  4
2           2  3  7  4
3           3  4  2  4
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an object, not a function

```
class DataWrapper:

    def run(self, df):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def open_and_run(self, file_in_location, delimiter=','):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_in_location, delimiter=delimiter)
        return self.run(df)

    def open_run_and_save(self, file_in_location, file_out_location,  delimiter=','):
        df_result = self.open_and_run(file_in_location, delimiter)
        df_result.to_csv(file_out_location, delimiter=delimiter)
```

Your wrapper functions would be implemented in the run method, and parameters would be passed on the initializer

```
class AddConstantColumnWrapper(DataWrapper):

    def __init__(self, colname, value):
        super().__init__()
        self.colname = colname
        self.value = value
 
    def run(self, df):
        df[self.colname] = self.value
        return df
```

Then you could call the object to perform what you need

```
wrapper = AddConstantColumnWrapper('C',4)
df_result = wrapper.open_and_run(file_in_location)
```

Passing a dictionary of parameters as an argument generally is indicative for the need of object orientation

Comment: I think you might be right, and I'm admittedly not as familiar with the use of classes (as you point out: likely whoever is running into this issue has been avoiding them and is using the workaround of passing dictionaries). That said, your example suggests that I'd need to create a class for each function I want to wrap. Or is it that rather than writing the function, I re-write it as a class (maybe this is best practice anyhow?), with the wrapper as a superclass?

Comment: It would be better to rewrite the functions as classes, as yourself mentioned, you would need a class for each method anyway, but if you want minimal effort to wrap the function in a class you could just copy-paste it on the same .py file, pass the needed parameters on the __init__ and call it on the run() method implementation